# Not able to use Option parser to run script in CMD

Tags: python, cmd

I recently want to use the script [Wikiextractor](https://github.com/attardi/wikiextractor) to perform extraction from a Wikipedia Cirrus dumps.

After "git clone" all the files, when I invoke the script directly, It worked just fine

```
C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\wikiextractor>python wikiextractor.py enwiki-pages-articles.xml.bz2
```

But I also want to install it (by running the setup.py provided) and use it in other directory.
After I successfully install wikiextractor, I cd to the directory with the same file (enwiki-pages-articles.xml.bz2) and try to run the script again.

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop\Wikidump>wikiextractor.py enwiki-pages-articles.xml.bz2
```

The following error message appears.

```
usage: WikiExtractor.py [-h] [-o OUTPUT] [-b n[KMG]] [-c] [--json] [--html]
                    [-l] [-s] [--lists] [-ns ns1,ns2]
                    [--templates TEMPLATES] [--no-templates] [-r]
                    [--min_text_length MIN_TEXT_LENGTH]
                    [--filter_disambig_pages] [-it abbr,b,big]
                    [-de gallery,timeline,noinclude] [--keep_tables]
                    [--processes PROCESSES] [-q] [--debug] [-a] [-v]
                    input
WikiExtractor.py: error: the following arguments are required: input
```

Why could this happen? 
I hope I explain everything clear.